# How do I prevent Virt-Viewer from capturing keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: debian, keyboard-shortcuts, virtual-machine

I am using Debian 11, virt-manager and LXD to do virtualization.

I need a way to prevent virt-viewer from capturing things like <kbd>Super</kbd> key, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd>, the number pad, etc. 
I use a **lot** of keyboard shortcuts that are designed for my workflow outside the virtual environment;
everything from adjusting volume to quickly taking notes to managing my time tracking system is done with keyboard shortcuts.

VirtualBox and `spicy` both have options for this. And since virt-viewer is supposed to be a more up to date version of `spicy`, it's frustrating to see this feature missing or buried someplace unintuitive.

In `spicy` the option is shown here: [image]

I would use `spicy` and not virt-viewer, but `spicy` won't open multiple windows (and since it's no longer supported, I can't make a feature request).

I just need to replicate that checkbox option in virt-viewer.

Related to [issue #72](https://gitlab.com/virt-viewer/virt-viewer/-/issues/72)

Answer (score 2):

Just press and release the <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> keys (together). 
Once you release those keys will get out of the capturing. 
To get into capturing keyboard do the same thing
(press and release the <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> keys once again).